# How to reinitialize a CLI application between some interval (Like reinitiate elinks between some interval in the same terminal window)?

Tags: command-line, terminal, terminal.app, gnome-terminal, elinks

I am using Elinks for specific page where I have to reload the page between every one minute. To reload it I have to press Ctrl+R shortcut to work it out. Can I automate this procedure? I tried to change the elink.conf file with the following line :

> set document.browse.refresh = 1
>
> set document.browse.minimum_refresh_time = 1000

It should reload the page at the interval of 1 second (1000 milliseconds), but nothing occurs.

After that I gave up and started to approach to a new procedure.
If there would be a command which can reinitialize the that app with the same argument it can do the same purpose.

As an example let's take I want to reload google.com at the interval of 1 minute, so if could have a terminal tool which can generate the same terminal command

> elinks https://google.com

in the same terminal window, it will do the same purpose.

I read the manual page of gnome-terminal but it does not have any option.

Thank you guys for you help in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Well I was looking for the solution and I found a tool or command called 'watch'. It is not the best way to refresh the page but it is usable. You can use the following command:

> watch -n 30 "elinks https://google.com"

The above command will refresh google.com after every seconds 60. But in this window you can not use the elinks software, you can only watch it refreshing. Saves my purpose. If you guys find a better solution, please let me know.

[screenshot_of_the_terminal_window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAuRe.png)

This is the screenshot of the terminal window.
It will show the update interval and current time with date.